# Footer in position fixed with Jquery slideUp needs fluidity

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slideup

My footer is in Position fixed, I need to adjust my code that currently the button Up and Down doesn't follow the slide smoothly. Please check my fiddle below to understand what I mean.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/408/)

My Jquery

```
 (function ($) {
        $('#vhiecles-opener').slideUp();
        $('#carousel-opener').unbind().bind('click', function () { loginSlideDown() });

        var loginSlideDown = function () {
            $('#carousel-opener').unbind();
            $('.selected-car').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#vhiecles-opener').slideToggle(500, function () {
                $('#carousel-opener').css({position: "fixed" , bottom: '184px'});
                $('#carousel-opener a.arrow').addClass('active');

                $('#carousel-opener').bind('click', loginSlideUp);
            });
        };

        var loginSlideUp = function () {
            $('#carousel-opener').unbind().slideDown(500);
            $('.selected-car').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#vhiecles-opener').slideToggle(500, function () {
                $('#carousel-opener').css({position: "fixed" , bottom: '62px'});
                $('#carousel-opener a.arrow').removeClass('active');
                $('#carousel-opener').bind('click', loginSlideDown);
            });
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: fixed MYSELF http://jsfiddle.net/QrrpB/410/thanks anyway, I hope you can use this

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, rather than moving 2 elements independently, it'd be better to just move the one containing element, added bonus being you get much smoother performance.

I've written a quick fiddle demonstrating what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nxLB/1/